# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (20, 3000) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(20, 200)'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

as an exercise I am trying to train a classification model using Tensorflow v1 without using keras nor sklearn nor any other library that would greatly ease my life.. lol.

I keep getting this error though and I can't figure out what's wrong about my code :

```
# imports
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O

import os,shutil, cv2, itertools

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior() # use Tensorflow v1
```

For simplicity I resized every image to 64 x 64.

Since there are 3 channels, size of input vector X wiz n is 64 x 64 x 3 (=12288).

To reduce computation time I only use 3000 images from the training data.

```
TRAIN_DATA_DIR_PREFIX = '/kaggle/input/cat-and-dog/training_set/training_set/'
TRAIN_DATA_DOG_DIR = TRAIN_DATA_DIR_PREFIX + 'dogs/'
TRAIN_DATA_CAT_DIR = TRAIN_DATA_DIR_PREFIX + 'cats/'

N_x = 64 * 64 * 3

TRAIN_DOG = [(TRAIN_DATA_DOG_DIR+i, 1) for i in os.listdir(TRAIN_DATA_DOG_DIR) if i.endswith(".jpg")]
TRAIN_DOG = TRAIN_DOG[:1500]

TRAIN_CAT = [(TRAIN_DATA_CAT_DIR+i, 0) for i in os.listdir(TRAIN_DATA_CAT_DIR) if i.endswith(".jpg")]
TRAIN_CAT = TRAIN_CAT[:1500]

TRAIN_DATA = TRAIN_DOG + TRAIN_CAT

print('TRAIN_DATA :', len(TRAIN_DATA))

def read_image(file_path):
    image = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return cv2.resize(image, (64, 64),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

def prepare(data):
    X = np.ndarray((N_x,len(TRAIN_DATA)), dtype=np.uint8)
    print ("X shape is {}".format(X.shape))
    Y = np.zeros((1,len(TRAIN_DATA)))
    print ("Y shape is {}".format(Y.shape))
    for i,(image_path, y) in enumerate(data):
        Y[0,i] = y
        image = read_image(image_path)
        X[:,i] = np.squeeze(image.reshape((N_x,1)))
    return X,Y

X,Y = prepare(TRAIN_DATA)
```

Output:

```
TRAIN_DATA : 3000
X shape is (12288, 3000)
Y shape is (1, 3000)
```

Then I define my tf_train function:

```
def tf_train(X, Y, batch_size=20):
    # Dataset (inputs and labels)
    
    D=200
    
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, D])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 1])

    # random variable
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([D, 1],stddev=0.1))
    
    z=tf.matmul(x,W)
    
    # map x to inferred output function
    # a = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W))
    
    # Define loss and optimizer
    # cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-(y_*tf.log(a)+(1-y_)*tf.log(1-a)))
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=z, labels=y_))
    
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-2).minimize(cross_entropy)
    
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run() #initializes W and a
    
    # Train
    for epoch in range (3000):
        idx = np.random.choice(len(TRAIN_DATA), batch_size, replace=False)
        #idx = np.random.permutation(np.arange(X.shape[1])) [:batch_size]
        _, l = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: X[idx], y_: Y[0,idx]})
        if epoch%100 == 0:
            print('loss: '+str(l))
```

And then when I start training my model :

```
tf_train(X,Y)
```

I get this following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_34/1897119706.py in <module>
----> 1 tf_train(X,Y)

/tmp/ipykernel_34/2072834761.py in tf_train(X, Y, batch_size)
     28         idx = np.random.choice(len(TRAIN_DATA), batch_size, replace=False)
     29         #idx = np.random.permutation(np.arange(X.shape[1])) [:batch_size]
---> 30         _, l = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: X[idx], y_: Y[0,idx]})
     31         if epoch%100 == 0:
     32             print('loss: '+str(l))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    966     try:
    967       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 968                          run_metadata_ptr)
    969       if run_metadata:
    970         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1165                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
   1166                 'which has shape %r' %
-> 1167                 (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   1168           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
   1169             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (20, 3000) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(20, 200)'
```

Why do I keep getting this error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape your data because at the moment it is interpreted as `(12288, 3000)` which means 12288 samples with 3000 features for each sample. You probably want the shape `(3000, 12288)` or even `(3000, 64, 64, 3)`, so try this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.random.normal((12288, 3000))
Y = tf.random.normal((1, 3000))

X = tf.reshape(X, (3000, 64, 64, 3)) # or tf.transpose(X) if you want (3000, 12288)
Y = tf.transpose(Y)
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
```

```
(3000, 64, 64, 3)
(3000, 1)
```

And your code here is causing the actual problem:

```py
D = 200
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, D])
```

D should be 12288 or 64 x 64 x 3, depending on how you will reshape your data.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I transposed X and Y so now X shape is (3000, 12288) and Y shape is (3000, 1).  I also put D = 12880

Comment: Nope, I get this new error: TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got array([2282, 1114, 1884, 2812,  887,  381, 1723, 2031,  820, 2989,  314,
       1800,  372, 2219, 1937, 2313, 2264, 2154, 2168,  283])

Comment: This error is coming from `_, l = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: X[idx], y_: Y[0,idx]})`. However, please do not ask a whole new question based on this entirely new issue in the comments after your first problem was resolved. Accept this answer and ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212120/typeerror-only-integers-slices-ellipsis-tf-newaxis-and-scalar-tf-int32-tf-in